# Case Insensitive search using Stackmob iOS SDK

Tags: ios, stackmob

I am using Stackmob iOS SDK http://www.stackmob.com/devcenter/docs/Datastore-API to communicate with Stackmob backend of my app. I need a case insensitive search in table. How can i do this with Stackmob API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For case-insensitive search you can store values lower-cased, then lower-case your search string to do an exact equality match.

If you still need the original casing for your values, this can be stored in a separate field.

Hope that helps!

-Miles O'Connell, StackMob Engineer